# JQuery Accordion Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jsfiddle

I have two radio buttons, and I want something to display below them depending on which one the user selects. Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQv4n/22/)

Problem:
I can't seem to target the correct p therefore nothing shows up when a radio button is selected

Any idea why my code fails to work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple modification to your HTML code and also for JS

```
<form>
    <div class="accordion">  
        <input type="radio" name="recog" id="recog_yes" value="0" />
        <label for="recog">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="recog1" id="recog_no" value="1" />
        <label for="recog">No</label>

        <p>  
            show this for yes
        </p>

        <p>  
            show this for no
        </p>                
    </div>

</form>
```

Any `input` or `select` controls must be integrated into `form` tag.

And js:

```
$(function(){
    $('.accordion p').hide();

    $('.accordion input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       $('.accordion p').hide();   

        $('.accordion input[type="radio"]').removeAttr("checked");

        $(this).prop("checked", true);

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
           $("p").eq($(this).val()).show();   
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/tQv4n/34/)

Seems a bug for jsfiddle (or not) in Firefox 15 and radio button is not selected/checked.

Comment: thank you but I really want to figure out this little bug. If you select one value it won't select another, the value changes but the radio button for the other one stays empty

Comment: Check the updated Js script and HTML (see the name for input radio). I figured that is a bug in Firefox if use jsfiddle.